# inner join results of "with" clause tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've 4 'with' clause tables as follows

```
with total_sales as (select sum("REVENUE") as summ from sql_sales) ,
     total_items as (select count("ID_ORDER") as oo from sql_sales) ,
     order_per_country as (select c."COUNTRY" as country, count(s."ID_ORDER") as orders
                        from sql_sales s
                        join sql_country c on s."ID_SELLER_COUNTRY" = c."ID_COUNTRY"
                        group by c."COUNTRY") , 
    revenue_per_country as (select c."COUNTRY" as country, sum(s."REVENUE") as REVENUE
                        from sql_sales s
                        join sql_country c on s."ID_SELLER_COUNTRY" = c."ID_COUNTRY"
                        group by c."COUNTRY")
```

now i'd like to display final table with 2 columns (each country) and  (revenue per country / total revenue across all countries) , but I don't know how

Comment: Fyi you have four *common table expressions*, or four CTEs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are complicating quite a bit the query, you can resolve it with basic sql aggregation:

```
select 
   c.COUNTRY as country, 
   sum(s.REVENUE)/(select sum(REVENUE) as total_revenue from sql_sales) as Percentage
from sql_country c
  join sql_sales s
    on s.ID_SELLER_COUNTRY = c.ID_COUNTRY
group by c.COUNTRY
```

Comment: but i want the final table to have a percentage of (global revenue / revenue per country) and same for orders

Comment: Where is that in the question?

Comment: (revenue per country / total sales) , i suppose to have 2 values , total sales across all countries , and sales per each country . your table does the latter , but how can retrieve all sales here in that query

Comment: revenue per country/total sales is an average, not a percentage. And you don't say either anything about global revenues. If you want the average, just use `avg` function

Comment: sorry about my English , but i think it's a percentage since it's what each country contributes to the total sales

Comment: again sorry about my bad english and my explanation , but as seen in original post , I want the sum of all revenue across all countries , AND revenue per country . So the final table should display (revenue per country / total revenue)

Comment: ok... Check if the new query fits your needs

Comment: yup , thank you so much , and can u please edit the query since you put 'ss' instead of just one 's' and it gives an error .

Comment: You are welcome, I have already changed the alias.

Comment: yes , but you didn't update (s.REVENUE) , it suppose to be  (ss.REVENUE)  instead

Comment: You are right, changed